Syllabus for the bs and ms in mathematical and theoritical statistics
I am a computer science undergrad who is very much interested in learning rigorous statistics both mathematically and the practical applications in real world.
I searched through online to find the brochure of bs in statistics but could not not find any . If anyone can share the brochure of bs and ms in Aristide of the reputed institutions like Oxford , Stanford etc then it would be greatly helpful for me to know statistics.
I as I have mentioned I want to learn statistics as mathematically rigorous as possible and also want many problems which requires statistical principles to be solved. Any advice to do so will be highly appreciated.

Hello! What does "the brochure" mean in this context?

Could you please spell out the acronyms? This will make the text and the title easier to read.

In India brochure is the document which contains all the courses and the elective that is going to be taught in the bs and ms courses along with the referred books .

I don't think the question as stated is really appropriate here.  That said, I hope it's useful to know that "catalog" is the usual term in the United States, at least, and that such sites are pretty easy to search (if sometimes obtuse), e.g. here is one of Stanford's programs.
